# Spring data redis override default serializer

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am trying to create a `RedisTemplate` bean which will have the updated value serializer to serialize an object in `JSON` format in redis.

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {

  @Bean(name = ["redisTemplate"])
  @Primary
  fun template(factory: RedisConnectionFactory): RedisTemplate<Any, Any> {
    val template = RedisTemplate<Any, Any>()
    template.connectionFactory = factory
    template.valueSerializer = Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object::class.java)
    template.afterPropertiesSet()
    return template
  }
}
```

As per my understanding, spring should use the JSON serializer to serialize the object returned by the methods marked with `Cacheable` annotation. Despite this configuration, spring seems to be using the default Java serializer as this exception confirms this fact.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: en.prateekj.vds.dto.Task
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:46)
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63)
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:94)
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:43)
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:219)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.serializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:238)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:144)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:770)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:398)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:314)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
```

Am I missing any configuration or something by which spring is not able to determine what `RedisTemplate` to use?

Answer (score 20):

You have probably solved it meanwhile, but for further answer seekers.

According to spring data redis [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer):

> By default, RedisCache and RedisTemplate are configured to use Java native serialization.

From stacktrace I can see that you are actually using Redis for caching, so you need to configure `RedisCache` and not `RedisTemplate`. `RedisCache` is not picking up your `@Bean` because it is not using `RedisTemplate` internally.

Example how you can do it in Java:

```
    @EnableCaching
    @Configuration
    public class CacheConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .serializeKeysWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()))
                .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)));
        }

    }
```