# Cache non-serializable objects using Spring Boot Cache backed by Redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-cache

I want to cache responses from a 3rd party API that provides its own client and data classes. The problem though, is that neither of the data classes implements the `Serialazable` interface, so caching using Spring Boot Cache Redis, throws `NotSerializableException` when I tried.

Is it somehow possible to configure the Spring Boot Redis Cache to allow caching of objects that doesn't implement `Serializable`?

Answer (score 0):

RedisCache is configured to use Java native serialization by default. You could try to change that like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971347/10371394), so RedisCache will use JSON serialization which does not require your resposes to be `Serializable`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but it leads to a set of new problems. Some problems I found still unanswered here on SO.